# Pycharm Error: Unresolved attribute reference 'isnumeric' for class 'int'

Tags: python, pycharm

I was messing with a code that ask 2 numbers and let the user input what operation to do with them.

I need the input to be integers only, so i used .isnumeric, but i just can't make it go thru and it displays this error either i input numbers or letters.

```
if num1.isnumeric():
```

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Can some of you show me where is the problem?

here's the full code:

```
print('Você deverá digitar dois números e depois selecionar qual operação fazer com ambos.\\n')

    while True:
    num1 = int(input('Digite o primeiro número: '))
    
    if num1.isnumeric():
        break
    else:
        print("Apenas números, por gentileza")
    
    while True:
    num2 = int(input('Digite o segundo número: '))
    
    if num2.isnumeric():
        break
    else:
        print("Apenas números, por gentileza")
    
    operador = input()
    
    if operador == '+':
    print('O resultado é:', num1 + num2)
    elif operador == '-':
    print('O resultado é:', num1 - num2)
    elif operador == '*':
    print('O resultado é:', num1 * num2)
    elif operador == '/':
    print('O resultado é:', num1 / num2)
    
    else:
    print('operador invalido')
```

I don't know what to try.

Comment: `num1` is the result of a call to `int()` - it cannot possibly be anything other than numeric!  If you wanted to handle non-numeric input yourself (rather than letting the program die with a ValueError), you'd have to check the string returned by `input()`, *before* applying `int()` to it.

Comment: `.isnumeric()` is a method of strings, which tells you if all the characters in the string are numeric. You turn the string into an integer first, and the int doesn't have that method (because it makes no sense, after all an integer doesn't consist of characters, it just has an integer numeric value)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Since you already used ```int(input(...))```, both ```num1``` and ```num2``` are already integers.  If you do need to check, use ```if isinstance(num1, int):``` to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isnumeric()` is a function of `str`. You need to remove the `int` from surrounding the `input` and move it to after you have verified that `isnumeric()` is `True`.

You also have incorrect indenting.  I don't know if that was just an issue when pasting the code into StackOverflow, but to sum it up, after a line that ends with a colon (`:`), the next line needs to have an increased indent, continuing until the end of the selection/iteration code block.

Read more about indentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp).